# Netlogo, Finding the closest agent based on link distance

Tags: netlogo

[image]

Hi everyone, So I am trying to solve a netlogo model where there are nodes linked to each other. Its a search and rescue based model where there are two types of agents population-agents and rescue-agents, whom are placed on a node.
Similar to the image below, where orange and purple nodes represent nodes on which there is an pop/resc agent. The Rescue-agents need to find the closest population agent based on the links distance, and travel to them. The link distances for example are the numbers shown on the image below. (Note the idea is not to use min-one-of in-radius command which will give the closest distance as to the closest link distance)
Any idea on how to find the closest population agent to each resc-agent?

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for the networks extension, which contains the primitives `nw:turtles-in-radius` and `nw:weighted-distance-to` to calculate distances along links.

Answer (score 2):

Yep managed to solve the problem. But it involves making many list. If ANY ONES GOT A BETTER SOLUTION OR IMPROVING THE FOLLOWING CODE. PLS DO LET ME KNOW. THANKS :)

I managed it to solve it by creating 3 lists, 
1. a list for all the population agents (N-pop-list)
2. a list for all the nodes the population agents are on (N-pop-node-list)
3. and a list for distances, where each node will calculate the distance from itself to the node the pop-agents on. (N-pop-distance-list)

```
globals [G-target-agent G-node-target-agent]
breed [pop-agents pop-agent]
breed [resc-agents resc-agent]
breed [nodes node]

pop-agents-own [node-pop (;node the pop agents on)]
resc-agents-own [node-resc (;node resc-agents on) target-agent (;agent they want to 
travel to) target-pop-agent-at (;node target-pop-agents on)]
nodes-own [N-pop-list N-pop-node-list N-pop-distance-list]
links-own [dist (pretty much length/distance of the link !)]

...
to setup-lists

ask nodes [
let temp-pop-list []
let temp-pop-node-list []
set N-pop-distance-list []

ask pop-agents[
  set temp-pop-list lput self temp-pop-list
  set temp-pop-node-list lput node-pop temp-pop-node-list
]
set N-pop-list temp-pop-list
set N-pop-node-list temp-pop-node-list

foreach N-pop-node-list
[[i] ->
  let dist-to-node nw:weighted-distance-to i dist
  set N-pop-distance-list lput dist-to-node N-pop-distance-list
]
]
end

to search-pop-agent
ask resc-agent[
ask node-resc[
let min-val min N-pop-distance-list
let min-val-pos position min-val N-pop-distance-list
set G-target-agent item min-val-pos N-pop-list 
set G-node-pop-agent-at item min-val-pos N-pop-node-list
]
set target-agent G-target-agent
set node-pop-agent-at G-node-pop-agent-at
]
end
```

Comment: I can't figure out what any of your lists are supposed to do. Why are you not just using `min one-of nw:weighted-distance-to` to find the closest along links?

Comment: From what i understood, maybe i am incorrect. nw:weighted-distance-to, return a distance. I am interested in finding the closest pop-agent to a resc-agent (Both agents are placed on nodes) based on the link distance. Something similar to, ask resc-agent(set target-agent min-one-of pop-agents in-radius 5 [distance myself]

Comment: As for the lists N-pop-distance-list contains the distance from every node to nodes containing pop-agents. i.e if there are 5 nodes with pop-agents on them, every node in the model will map the distance to these 5 nodes. its a list of distances [23 4 6 7 9]. The other two lists simply contain the Node who number and Pop-agent who number [pop-agent 1 3 4 6 7] [Node 82 77 65 44 56]. So by finding the position of the minimum value in the distance list, you can find the corresponding pop-agent and the node its on. In this instance the min distance is 4. Hence the pop-agent is 3 and node is 77.

Comment: `nw:weighted-distance-to` calculates the total distance along the (links) path, taking into account the weights for each link